# How would I conditionally add or remove a hover effect?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I want to be able to pass in a prop when initializing a component whose value will be used to dictate whether the hover effect is active or not. How would I go about doing this?

For example, if you don't want the hover effect to be active on an instance of a `<Button />` component then you'd be able to do something like this `<Button hover="someValue"/>` and the hover effect would be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you just use some boolean property for that, if you want it to be enabled by default, just set it to `true`:

```js
export let hover = true; // Value used if not set on component
```

If `someValue` is supposed to be local state you would have to pass it like this:

```html
<Button hover={someValue} />
```

You can of course also invert the logic and use a default of `false`.

The value would then be used in the component to add or not add a class, e.g.

```html
<div class:hover >...</div>
```